# Cassandra Point-in-Time Recovery with commitlog_archiving.properties

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to do Point-in-Time recovery in Cassandra using commitlog_archiving.properties, below is my configuration in commitlog_archiving.properties.

archive_command=/bin/cp -f %path /cassandra_path/archived_commit/%name

restore_command=/bin/cp -f %from %to

restore_directories=/cassandra_path/archived_commit

restore_point_in_time=2017:07:25 12:40:00
precision=MILLISECONDS

Now, I inserted 10 records with cql. Then I flush with nodetool, stopped Cassandra and deleted commitlog files. When I started Cassandra, it restoring the data from archived_commitlog and then it replay those commitlogs. But unfortunately it recovering all the records even after the "restore_point_in_time"(time is in GMT).

Please help on this, thanks in advance.